# Anonymous inner classes JAXB serialization

Tags: java, spring, serialization, jaxb, anonymous

I tried to use anonymous inner classes with initializers syntax to serialize JAXB generated objects, and noticed that it works on endpoints but not with RestTemplate. I am wondering why is it working in one case and not the other?

To give example, this is sample endpoint in Spring which returns JAXB generated Profile instance:

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = SERVICE_NAME)
@ResponsePayload
public Profile getProfile(@RequestPayload  GetProfile request) {

    // do stuff with service that returns Profile
    return service.doStuff(request);

}
```

Now, when i have service returning the anonymous instance of Profile, there are no serialization issues:

```
return new Profile() {

    {
        setBirthday(user.getBirthday());
        setEmailAddress(user.getEmailAddress());
        setFirstname(user.getFirstname());
        setGender(user.getGen());
        // and so on
    }
};
```

However, when i try to use anonymous inner classes as argument to RestTemplate, then i get JAXB error regarding the not supported anonymous classes.

"a non-static inner class, and JAXB can't handle those.
    this problem is related to the following location..."

```
    private UpdateProfile createUpdateProfileRequest(final UpdateProfile request) {


    return new UpdateProfile() {

        {
            setProfileV2(getProfile(request));
        }
    };

}


private ProfileV2 getProfile(UpdateProfile request) {

    ProfileV2 profile = new ProfileV2();

    ProfileUpdate profileUpdate = request.getProfileUpdate();

    profile.setBirthday(profileUpdate.getBirthday());
    profile.setFirstname(profileUpdate.getFirstname());


    return profile;

}
```

I have read this post:
[What is Double Brace initialization in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java/27521360#27521360)

And i generally don't have use case where these objects could turn into container managed singletons - memory leaks.

There is a mention of serialization issues, but no details and i would like to understand this.

Since i am using JAXB for serialization on endpoints too, why it is possible for JAXB to serialize such objects as outgoing data on endpoints but not within RestTemplate.postForObject(...).

Comment: Do you really gain anything by using double-brace initialization, vs just creating an instance, calling the methods, and returning the instance?

Comment: There is no concrete gain, i was just wondering why does it not work. Static didn't help. But i think now that issue might be that this service(Spring singleton) implements Generic interface. This interface is then parameterized with Profile in service implementation.

Comment: Then again, i have same structure with interfaces when i generate responses and it works.

Comment: Are the other places in `static` methods?

Comment: Nope, no static methods in both cases. Just spring managed Beans without static fields/methods.